# Symfony routing resource and Bundle name

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I an trying to include a file into the Symfony 4 routes, and can't figure out what would be the correct way to put in the Bundle name. 
My routes.yml:

```
icatcher_builder:
    # loads routes from the given routing file stored in some bundle
    resource: '@ICatcher/Builder/Resources/config/routes.yaml'
```

My bundles.php:

```
App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
```

And I get this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Bundle "ICatcher" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you
>   forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your
>   App\Kernel.php file? in @ICatcher/Builder/Resources/config/routes.yaml
>   (which is being imported from "[PATH]\config/routes.yaml"). Make sure
>   the "ICatcher/Builder/Resources/config/routes.yaml" bundle is
>   correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If
>   the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path
>   "@ICatcher/Builder/Resources/config/routes.yaml" is not empty.").

If I just copy the routes into the main route.yml file instead of including an external resource - all works fine.

Comment: And is the bundle enabled? The error looks pretty explicit.

Comment: Check you name space on your bundle, probably ICatcher\Builder\Builder::class

Comment: The Bundle is enabled - it runs if I just copy the routes to the App's routes.yaml, it only throws the error when I try to include Bundle's routes.yaml. 
I think I don't understand the syntax - what Symfony considers the 'name' of the bundle?

Comment: ICatcher\Builder\Builder::class tried that and App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder::class doesn't work, and without the '::class' doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony has strict rules of naming Bundle classes, which I found out here in the documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html

So my Bundle class is now re-named from `App\ICatcher\Builder\Builder` to `App\ICatcher\Builder\ICatcherBuilder` and the file is re-named the same way `ICatcherBuilder.php` and it works.